# JQuery wiggle delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

Using the JQuery wiggle plugin: http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/jquery.wiggle/demo/
How can I do something like this?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.manpoints.uk.to/js/wiggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".large_image").click(function() {
    $(this).wiggle('start').delay(800).wiggle('stop');
  });
});
```

Currently I get a response "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'delay'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method is not chainable with `delay()`, try this:

```
$(".large_image").click(function() {
    $(this).wiggle('start');
}).delay(800).queue(function(){
   $(this).waggle('stop')
})
```

Comment: delay isn't a Wiggle function :(  Yours touches the jQuery delay

Comment: He's not wanting though. He's tring to use the delay _option_ from the wiggle plugin. His comment on my correct answer also reflects this.

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease note that delay is used for jquery animating methods like fadeIn, hide and animate.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't use delay for this: Image clicked -> Wiggle starts -> delay for 800ms -> wiggle stops ?

Comment: no, you can use it,  i have updated ma answer, hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation (albeit limited), `delay` is *not* a function. It's an option. I can't say for certain, but I think the syntax might look like:

```
$(".large_image").click(function() {
    $(this).wiggle('start',{delay:800}).wiggle('stop');
});
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. Read documentation better Josh Luke Blease ;)

Comment: No problem! I tested it out in chrome's console from their site and it works (although I didn't but the stop call after start to ensure it works.

Comment: It does, but you have stop called right after. If you want to see the wiggle with the actual delay, remove the stop call that immediately follows.

Comment: All your code does is slow down the delay between rotations as said in the documentation. This is wasn't what I wanted, sorry.